# Handy way to combine vectors of different lengths

Tags: r, list, vector, lapply, flatten

I am trying to build a single vector that holds elements of several vectors with different lengths. As an example, let's consider three vectors:

```
x <- rnorm(5,0,1)
y <- rnorm(2,0,1)
z <- rnorm(3,0,1)
```

To get this done in a handy, I used the sapply function as follows

```
set.seed(123)
vec <- sapply(c(5,2,3), function(n) rnorm(n,0,1))
```

but this lists them as separate vectors

```
[[1]]
[1] -0.5605 -0.2302  1.5587  0.0705  0.1293

[[2]]
[1] 1.715 0.461

[[3]]
[1] -1.265 -0.687 -0.446
```

Is there away of improving this code or applying some other functions to have the three vectors as a single vector so that it appears as

```
[1] -0.5605 -0.2302  1.5587  0.0705  0.1293 1.715 0.461 -1.265 -0.687 -0.446
```

Any help is well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `unlist` to convert a list into a vector.

```
unlist(sapply(c(5,2,3), function(n) rnorm(n,0,1)))

[1]  0.2185724 -1.4715697 -1.5881170 -0.5791368 -1.1028307
[6] -0.5208913 -0.7065582  0.1414712  0.6883996  0.3030542
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using `purrr::map_dfr`:

```r
set.seed(123)
purrr::map_dfr(c(5,2,3), ~data.frame(V1 = rnorm(.x, 0, 1)))$V1

#>  [1] -0.56047565 -0.23017749  1.55870831  0.07050839  0.12928774  1.71506499
#>  [7]  0.46091621 -1.26506123 -0.68685285 -0.44566197
```

The similar solution to `unlist` in `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
as_vector(map(c(5,2,3), ~rnorm(.x, 0, 1)))
```

Comment: as_vector has other uses too. I believe `list_c` was created to suit this case perfectly

Answer (score 1):

We can also `Reduce` the `c`oncatenate function over the list (1),
or use `purrr::list_c`

```
Reduce(c, vec)

#OR#

library(purrr) #(requires purrr version 1.0.0)

list_c(vec)

 [1] -0.56047565 -0.23017749  1.55870831  0.07050839  0.12928774
 [6]  1.71506499  0.46091621 -1.26506123 -0.68685285 -0.44566197
```

`unlist` is definitelly the way yo go, though.